# How does a HTTP client authenticate itself with a HTTP server?

Tags: tls, authentication, http

Is it correct that there are various ways that a HTTP client can authenticate itself with a HTTP server?

Are the following such ways?

1. authorization header: for various authorization protocols (e.g. basic, digest, ...)
2. digital certificates: as used in HTTPS.
3. specify user name and passwords in HTTP request's message body, by applying HTTP POST method on form data

Are they used individually or together? Are they used for the same or different purposes? When is each way used?

In the second way, is digital certificates specified in some HTTP request header(s)? (In curl, it is specified via `--cerf`)

In the third way, when specify user name and passwords in HTTP request's message body, are they encrypted? Does the server know how to decrypt them?

Comment: The server sets up authentication however it wants. You could embed the password as ASCII art if you wanted to. As a result there isn't really an answer to any of these questions. This is a lot like asking "how do people eat food?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it correct that there are various ways that a HTTP client can authenticate itself with a HTTP server?

Yes. There are many, many ways. Custom authentications schemes are common.

> Are the following such ways?
>
> 1. authorization header: for various authorization protocols (e.g. basic, digest, ...)
> 2. digital certificates: as used in HTTPS.
> 3. specify user name and passwords in HTTP request's message body, by applying HTTP POST method on form data

Yes. Those are all ways authentication can happen. Although, **nota bene**, client certificate authentication usually involves the `Authorization` header with protocol = digest. Also sending username and password in a POST body is <s>sloppy unless you're creating an account. It works, but it's sloppy.</s> unusual unless the request is coming from an actual HTML form.

> Are they used individually or together? Are they used for the same or different purposes? When is each way used?

Only one authentication scheme is used at a time. Digest authentication is used when [replay attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) are a real threat. Digest authentication involves a [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) such that the same MAC will not work twice. Basic authentication is more vulnerable to replay attacks but TLS encryption would need to be broken (or absent) to make this possible.

Client certificates are used when the server wants to check the veracity of the client's claimed identity using a [trusted third party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority).

> In the second way, is digital certificates specified in some HTTP request header(s)? (In curl, it is specified via `--cerf`)

The client certificate itself would be specified in the body of an HTTP request. Client certificate authentication requires multiple requests and responses passed *statefully*.

> In the third way, when specify user name and passwords in HTTP request's message body, are they encrypted? Does the server know how to decrypt them?

They are encrypted if the request body itself is encrypted. This is the case in any `https` request. If you want details of the encryption and decryption system, read about TLS/SSL.

Comment: Sloppy to send login/password in a `POST`?! Most every CMS I've encountered (such as Wordpress) does just that. For an API it's less likely you'd want to use such, but that doesn't make it sloppy.

Comment: Thanks. 1) "Basic authentication is more vulnerable to replay attacks but TLS encryption would need to be broken (or absent) to make this possible." Do you mean basic authentication is always/often used with TLS i.e. HTTPS?  2) "Client certificates are used when the server wants to check the veracity of the client's claimed identity using a trusted third party." In HTTPS, is client certificate used always/often? 3) In most cases, which way(s) (including not listed in my post) is used for client to authenticate itself to server?

Comment: @AlexisWilke I’m not saying you’re wrong, but I would genuinely be interested to see evidence of wp using username and password in POST body for something other than new user registration. Admittedly, I was imagining an API.

Comment: @Tim 1) Yes, basic authentication should never be used without TLS unless you are on very trusted subnet (i.e. IPC through localhost). 2) HTTP client certificate authentication is rare, in my experience. 3) By far the most common authentication method on the modern internet is [token authentication](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/) using tokens saved in cookies and refreshed periodically. The most common method of obtaining the token is `Basic` authentication. Check out [OAuth2](https://oauth.net/2/).

Comment: Definitely still a POST. Simple form + POST = easy to implement. [Here is a screenshot](http://alexis.m2osw.com/images/wordpress-uses-post.png) (a bit deleted for privacy) which shows the the first thing that happens when I click Login is a POST and I show the parameters to the right side.

Comment: @AlexisWilke That’s pretty interesting. I concede. I will edit my answer accordingly. Thanks for actually following through. I learned something today.

Comment: @WilliamRosenbloom Thanks. 1) Basic authentication uses base64 encoding. Can its encoded code be decoded easily? 2) "By far the most common authentication method on the modern internet is token authentication using tokens saved in cookies and refreshed periodically." Does that apply only to web services? For web applications, are user passwords provided by POST on form data? What is the most common method for web applications?

Comment: @Tim 1) Yes. base64 encoding is not encryption. It is just a different way of writing data. It is no more secure than plain text. 2) As I'm sure you've experienced, most webapps only require you to authenticate with a password at the beginning of sessions. That is because the password is used to obtain a token, which authenticates from then on. Often this password is provided through POST data, if you login through an HTML form.

Comment: Your edit doesn't help. Sending email+pass in a POST is not just usual but the norm for forms and API calls. How else are you supposed to login a user

Comment: @ConorMancone are you kidding? All the other forms of authentication in this thread come to mind. But most obvious would be with `Authorization: Basic ...`.

Comment: @WilliamRosenbloom Thanks. 1) Is it correct that putting user passwords into message bodies of HTTP requests is at web application level, which is higher than the HTTP level, because HTTP doesn't interpret the content of the message bodies, while web applications do? 2) Since user passwords can be put into cookies and URLs as query strings (although bad idea), I was wondering if these two ways are also at the web application level not at the HTTP level? Does the HTTP protocol also not interpret the contents of cookies and query strings of URL? See https://security.stackexchange.com/q/225606

Comment: @Tim 1) It is correct that are no rules in HTTP about how to interpret passwords in a message body. I don't know what you mean by "web application level". 2) Passwords are not put into cookies. *Tokens* are put into cookies. Also, unlike message bodies, [cookies are regulated by HTTP](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265). But HTTP does not specify how contents of cookies should be used for authentication. This is left to the web-app.

Comment: @Tim this forum is for specific questions seeking answers, whereas this has been more of a starting point for a discussion. What is your motivation for asking these questions? Perhaps the list of questions can be consolidated into something more concrete? Otherwise, I would recommend moving to a reddit-style discussion forum.

Comment: Thanks. my motivation is simply to clear confusions and improve understanding. Sorry for dragging you into more questions.

Comment: @Tim If you are interested in a less technical overview of the HTTP standards around cookies, Mozilla has excellent [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies). I also recommend you edit your other question to remove the reference to passwords in cookies. Also, there is nothing wrong with putting a password in a query string under TLS. The path, fragment, and query string all get encrypted by TLS.

Comment: There is the confusion - I was referring to the actual login, and the screenshot that @AlexisWilke gave is for the login process. The methods being discussed only work **after** the user first logs in, but that first login has to happen by email and password. So email/password are used for initial login but are not used after that - one of these methods is used instead. There aren't any systems where it continues to send up email and password on every request - that **would** be crazy and unusual.

Comment: @WilliamRosenbloom Thanks. About token authentication, ["The most common method of obtaining the token is Basic authentication."](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/225591/225594#comment461240_225594), and ["That is because the password is used to obtain a token, which authenticates from then on. Often this password is provided through POST data, if you login through an HTML form."](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/225591/225594#comment461250_225594). Do you mean a token can be obtained in two different common ways: basic authentication and HTML form?

Comment: Since this is a security site, I wanted to point out that one of the first implementations of "Remember Me", a plugin that was added to Wordpress would actually save the login & password to a cookie, unencrypted. Imagine the joy of the Wordpress hackers! (Note: it was not implemented by the Wordpress authors; it was an extension by someone else who didn't know much about security.)

Comment: @AlexisWilke that's an awesome little fact. You should message me if you're interested in a WP dev job.

Comment: @Tim There are many [ways to obtain tokens](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/). Both of the ways you mentioned would be acceptable.